# How to set background color for code chunks in Quarto when output is Beamer?

Tags: beamer, quarto

I have the following code for a `Quarto` document:

````
---
title: "Any stuff"
date: 10/12/23
date-format: long
format: 
  beamer:
    aspectratio: 169
jupyter: python3
pdf-engine: xelatex
highlight-style: atom-one
code-block-bg: true
code-block-border-left: "#31BAE9"
code-line-numbers: true
---

## First slide

- Some stuff
- more stuff

## Slide with code


```{python}
#| echo: true
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = x + 5
print("Hello, world")
```
````

No matter what I do, the code is printed against the white background of Beamer. It seems that Quarto is ignoring my command, although it throws no error:

[image]

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

Comment: x-post  https://stackoverflow.com/q/77276895/2777074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You chose

```
highlight-style: atom-one
```

that seems that is unable fo fix a background color, unlike other several styles, for instance, with `tango`:

```
highlight-style: tango
```

Then, the result is:

[image: mwe]

A simpler solution is add `#` before :

```
#    highlight-style: atom-one
```

That is, make it a comment and do not set any style, because the default style (`arrow`) also  admit a custom-background.